# How to use a Regular Expression to find a Specific word and return following 10 characters?

Tags: regex

I need to find a regular expression that finds "Order #" and then return the following 10 characters.

For example I can the following rows (Ignore row numbers just using them to designate that it is a new or next line in the original data):

```
Row 1 Order #100013661 By John DOE
Row 2 REFUND for CHARGE(Order #100013667 By Lara Croft
Row 3 Order #100013668 By Sammy
Row 4 Blah Blah Blah Order #10013664 By Fluffy fluff
```

I want the expression to return:

```
ROW 1 100013661
ROW 2 100013667
Row 3 100013668
Row 4 100013664
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you need is

```
(?<=Order #).{10}
```

Detailed explanation:

- `(?<=Order #)` is a positive lookbehind: it matches if the literal string `Order #` occurs before current position;
- `.{10}` matches any 10 characters.

Note that this won't match if your line has less than 10 characters in a line after the search string.  If you need to match *up to* 10 characters, not *exactly* 10 characters, replace `{10}` with `{1,10}`.

Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/TRB4Ep/1).

Comment: This worked great for my original dataset.  I now have a new string of data and the solutions above arent working. Here is the string - AVIDPAYCK16527Legum   I need to pull the 5 digit number.

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing groups for that:

```
Order #(.{9})
```

Use the tools in your hosting language to harvest the capturing group.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/RQqWKS/1)

Comment: The row number is not part of the string.

Comment: @Adam right, I didn't notice the "ignore" part in the text of the question. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Order #(.{10}) or Order #(.{1,10}) if it could be up to 10 characters.

Order #(\d{1,10}) if they are always numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your help!